# Are there any cooliris-like photo viewer to view photos in your local hard disk like a 3D wall gallery?

Tags: windows, gui, 3d, image-viewer, gallery

The Cooliris is a plugin for web browser to view photos in the web in 3D wall style as follows:

[image]

Are there any software that can do that on photos found in local hard disk and can shrink the gap between the photos?